# Is Xamarin Forms UWP Platform Broken for 64bit Builds?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Ive spent hours trying to get my Forms app working on UWP. I finally realised I had the Solution Platform drop-down in Visual Studio set to 64 bit. When I set it to AnyCPU or 32bit it works fine.

The error I see is when running against a 64bit build is:

**An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.**

I get this error in the constructor of the App.cs class in the portable project. The Stacktrace is:

**at Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter.get_Value()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsResourcesProvider.GetStyle(Object nativeKey)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsResourcesProvider.GetSystemResources()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Application..ctor()
   at TestForms.App..ctor()
   at TestForms.UWP.MainPage..ctor()
   at TestForms.UWP.TestForms_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage()
   at TestForms.UWP.TestForms_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()**

When I ***tried again with a brand new Xamarin Forms project*** I get the same issue when trying to run it in 64 bit mode.

I cant remember reading anything about Xamarin Forms UWP not being supported on 64 bit.

Can someone from Xamarin help me out ?

Thanks

Comment: if you're asking for a question from xamarin itself you should be on the xamarin forums. then again on stackoverflow most people will give you more useful advice than xamarin in a timely manner...

Comment: Well, Xamarin announced that StackOverflow was the go-to place for help from Xamarin now. So lets give it a try :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are hitting this bug:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33135

If you would like to receive a notification when the bug is updated, you can add yourself to the CC list for the bug.  Please note that you will need to create an account on that system if you have not already done so.

Comment: Thanks. I know UWP on forms is still in preview, but do you know when this is likely to be fixed . thanks again