# Xamarin Forms x64 support for Windows 10 (UWP)

Tags: xamarin, 64-bit, xamarin.windows

Does anybody know if is there x64 support for Xamarin Forms Windows 10?

**UPDATE**
As answered by Avi K.,
in the prerelease (i hope it will be stable) x64 support has been fixed
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33135

Thanks!

Comment: This is a knonw issue. Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541801/is-xamarin-forms-uwp-platform-broken-for-64bit-builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep this clean and to have a marked answer and close the topic, I want to reiterate that the latest pre-release of Xamarin.Forms 2.3.x contains support for 64bit.

Thanks!

Source: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33135#c24